# +Reference in the deployment does not match the identity defined in the application manifest

Tags: clickonce

Getting below error ,after have done the Sign .exe files with SignTool.exe and Appliation manifest and manifest with MageUi.exe.

```
SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/dev/SignAndPublish/artifactsWOTimeAll/bin/T3NAPackage/T3Services_Dev/T3ClientInstall/T3Client_DEV.application
    Application url         : file:///C:/dev/SignAndPublish/artifactsWOTimeAll/bin/T3NAPackage/T3Services_Dev/T3ClientInstall/Application%20Files/T3Client_DEV_2_0_0_573/T3Client_DEV.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : T3Client_DEV.application, Version=2.0.0.573, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\dev\SignAndPublish\artifactsWOTimeAll\bin\T3NAPackage\T3Services_Dev\T3ClientInstall\T3Client_DEV.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Reference in the deployment does not match the identity defined in the application manifest. 

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [9/14/2023 11:08:19 AM] : Activation of C:\dev\SignAndPublish\artifactsWOTimeAll\bin\T3NAPackage\T3Services_Dev\T3ClientInstall\T3Client_DEV.application has started.
    * [9/14/2023 11:08:19 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [9/14/2023 11:08:19 AM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [9/14/2023 11:08:19 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SubscriptionSemanticValidation)
        - Reference in the deployment does not match the identity defined in the application manifest. 
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I have to sign the both .exe and .manifest file and while launching the installer it should show the publisher name as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this apply to MageUI and your application but maybe it is about the same [limitation that manifests from MSIX packages](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/faq-msix.html#question235) encounter. In that case the publisher defined in the manifest much match 100% the publisher name from the digital certificate used to sign the package, otherwise signtool will fail.

Have you tried setting the same publisher in the manifest?